# Visualforce and LWC Security Concerns

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-web-components, security

I’m trying to find an example of security issues in VF or LWC. If that security vulnerability really exist in the code, and if that vulnerable code is deployed to a Salesforce prod org or Salesforce community, what would be the damage created for internal users/community users.

I need to know the vulnerability in the code as well as the resulting impact.

Comment: This question will most likely get closed citing "too broad to answer", but I've posted few details as answer. Take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Security Vulnerabilities in Salesforce (LWC, Visualforce or Apex) can occur in various forms, if the secure coding practices are not adhered to. It can be Cross Site Scripting, Cross Site Request Forgery, Clickjacking, SOQL injection etc and many more. This topic is is agnostic and extends beyond Salesforce platform. I've pasted text explaining a few of these from official Salesforce documentation.

**[Cross-site scripting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.secure_coding_guide.meta/secure_coding_guide/secure_coding_cross_site_scripting.htm)**

> Cross-site scripting is a vulnerability that occurs when an attacker
> can insert unauthorized JavaScript, VBScript, HTML, or other active
> content into a web page viewed by other users. A malicious script
> inserted into a page in this manner can hijack the user’s session,
> submit unauthorized transactions as the user, steal confidential
> information, or simply deface the page.

**[SOQL Injection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.secure_coding_guide.meta/secure_coding_guide/secure_coding_sql_injection.htm)**

> When queries are built directly with user data inlined or concatenated
> directly with the query text, instead of using type-safe bind
> parameters, malicious input may be able to change the structure of the
> query to bypass or change application logic. SQL injection flaws are
> extremely serious. A single flaw anywhere in your application may
> allow an attacker to read, modify or delete your entire database.

**[Cross Site Request Forgery](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.secure_coding_guide.meta/secure_coding_guide/secure_coding_cross_site_req_forgery.htm)**

> Cross-site request forgery (CSRF) occurs when a user visits a
> malicious web page that makes their browser send requests to your
> application that the user did not intend. This can be done with the
> src attribute of the IMG, IFRAME or other tags and more complicated
> requests, including POSTs, can be made using JavaScript. Because the
> browser always sends the relevant cookies when making requests,
> requests like this appear to originate from an authenticated user. The
> malicious site isn’t able to see the results of these requests, but if
> create, update or delete functionality can be triggered, the malicious
> site may be able to perform unauthorized actions.

**[Clickjacking](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.siteforce_clickjacking_enable.htm&type=5)**

> Clickjacking is a type of attack that tricks users to click something,
> such as a button or link, because they perceive they are clicking
> something safe. Instead, the button or link performs malicious actions
> on your site, leading to data intrusion, unauthorized emails, changed
> credentials, or other site-specific results.

The question is too broad to be answered here, so here are some links that would help you understand the vulnerabilities, their impact and whether some of them are implicitly taken care by Salesforce platform.

[Secure Coding Guidelines](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.secure_coding_guide.meta/secure_coding_guide/secure_coding_guidelines.htm): This guide details most security vulnerabilities, their impact and how to avoid the common coding pitfalls.

[LWC Security with Lightning Locker](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_locker_service): This link details the common security measures implemented by lightning locker. You might also want to read more about the Lightning Web Security which is a replacement to Lightning locker.

[Security Tips for Apex & VisualForce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_security_tips_intro.htm): This section with the developer guide outlines some security vulnerabilities, their impact and some best practices w.r.t to Apex and VisualForce.

[Platform Security FAQs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000318378&type=1): This article lists and details the vulenerabilities which as implicitly handled or via OOB configuration in Salesforce.

You can see from these articles (& text pasted above) that a single bad security/ coding practice can have devastating impact on the organization, mostly due to data leakage to hackers or denial of service to the org users.